# Triangular Numbers that are odd, less than 2000

Tags: elementary-number-theory, pattern-recognition

The diagram below shows the $1$st, $2$nd, $3$rd and $4$th triangular numbers.

> (1 spot)  : $1$
>
> (3 spots) : $3$
>
> (6 spots) : $6$
>
> (10 spots) : $10$

The formula $n(n + 1)/2$ can be used to find the $n$th triangular number.

For example the fifth triangular number is

$5(5 + 1) / 2 = 5 \times 6 / 2 = 15$

How many of the triangular numbers that are less than $2000$ are odd?

**My thought:** So I can see a pattern here: $1, 3, 6, 10, 15, 21, 28, 36, 45, 55, 66, 78 \ldots$. So after the first $3$ there is an equal number of odds and evens.

But that is a problematic way to calculate it. What is the easier way?

Comment: Where is the diagram? Have you copied this question from somewhere?

Comment: Sorry, yes, it is from a test sheet I am studying. The diagram is just of spotted triangles. I can't think how to show this with text.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- $\dfrac{n(n+1)}{2}<2000 \implies n^2+n-4000<0 \implies n<\dfrac{-1+\sqrt{16001}}{2}\approx62.75$
- $\dfrac{n(n+1)}{2}\not\equiv0\pmod2 \implies n(n+1)\not\equiv0\pmod4$

  $\implies [n\not\equiv0\pmod4]\wedge[(n+1)\not\equiv0\pmod4]$

  $\implies [n\not\equiv0\pmod4]\wedge[n\not\equiv3\pmod4]$

  $\implies [n\equiv1\pmod4]\vee[n\equiv2\pmod4]$
- Therefore $n\in\{1,2,5,6,9,10,\dots,61,62\}$
- Hence there are $\dfrac{62}{2}+1=32$ odd triangular numbers smaller than $2000$

Comment: I can't seem to suggest an edit to this from my phone but the second bullet point is: $\dfrac{n(n+1)}{2}\pmod2\equiv1 \implies$$ [n\equiv1\pmod4]\vee[n\equiv2\pmod4]$

Comment: @BeaumontTaz: And the point in quoting this bullet here is...?

Comment: It may just be the app on my phone, but that line of MathJax is showing a math processing error on my end.

Comment: @BeaumontTaz: Well, your first comment looks like you've simply copy-pasted that bullet from the answer.

Comment: I broke it into two math tags. For some reason it has to do with the '\implies' and the '[' after. So I just broke it into two different math tags. I was only trying to fix the MathJax, not the math. So it's supposed to look the same. Again, I'm on my phone and it may only be an issue on this end.

Comment: @BeaumontTaz: There is no change in the contents, and the "edited" link doesn't indicate that it was edited recently... And it looks fine from here (running in FF on a desktop).

Comment: I was able to borrow a computer for a second to check and it looks fine in Chrome too. But I'm using the StackExchange App for iPhone and it was throwing an error. I'm sure it's a problem with the app and not with the post. But it now here for anyone who uses the app and not a true browser.

Comment: Sorry, how do you get from: n2+n−4000<0 to n<63

Comment: @user1495024: I added that to the answer (though it's a simple quadratic equation to solve, which I would have expected you to know).

Answer (score 0):

Note that amongst the even numbers, multiples of $4$ alternate with multiples of $2$ which are not multiples of $4$.

If the even number out of $n$ and $n+1$ is a multiple of $4$, the triangle number will be even, otherwise it will be odd.

You can use this to show rigorously that pairs of odd triangle numbers alternate with pairs of even triangle numbers. Then you simply have to check what happens at the beginning of the list and at the end of the list to adjust for the boundary effects.

I don't know why you think that is a problematic way to calculate - it would also work for $2,000,000$ for example.

Comment: I don't think the question is well worded, but the hardest part (for me) is calculating the number of triangular numbers that are less than 2000 (i.e. they do not want the 2000th triangular number but the triangular numbers that are less than 2000)

Comment: The $n$th triangular number is given by $n(n+1)/2$ as noted above.  So to find how many triangular numbers are less than $2000$ you solve $n(n+1)/2 < 2000$.  That's a quadratic inequality, so you can use the quadratic formula to find the roots.  If you're still not sure which one you want, substitute them back into $n(n+1)/2$ and take $n$ which yields an answer less than 2000.

Comment: @user1495024 So $\sqrt {4000} \approx 63$ (note that $64^2=4096$ if you know your powers of $2$, and that $4000=2\times 2000$) so that the possibilities for the last triangle number before $2000$ are $64\cdot 63/2 = 2016$ or $62\cdot 63/2= 1953$

Answer (score 0):

Let's take the number to be:
$$N=\frac {n(n+1)}2$$
If it is odd it must not be divisible by two, so $n(n+1)$ must be divisible by 2 only once. As  when we take two consequtive numbers one of them must be even always, so, suppose:

### Case I

$n$ is even and divisible by two only once, then $n+1$ must be odd;

Possible numbers are:
$2,2\times3,2\times5,2\times7,...$

Or put it other ways it is of the form $2\times p$ where $p$ is a prime no., the pattern to which is not possible.

### CaseII

Consider similiarly (n+1)...